# dtoa-ftoa management of decimals in c

Tags: c

I would like to do a dtoa or ftoa, at least to have an array with my number and at least 10 decimals, but the problem it's after 4 decimals, the precision is <strike>not</strike> wrong <strike>anymore</strike>.

```
uintmax_t       ft_countdec(long double nbr, long double baselen)
{
    double      f;
    uintmax_t   ret;
    int i;

    f = nbr;
    i = 0;
    printf("%Lf\n", nbr);
    while ((nbr - ret) != 0)
    {
        nbr /= baselen;
        ret = (uintmax_t)nbr;
        i++;
        printf("\nboucle : nbr = %Lf ret = %ld\n", nbr,ret);
    }
    printf("%ld\n", ret);
    return (ret);
}

char    *ft_dtoa(long double n)
{
    uintmax_t   nb_one;
    uintmax_t   nb_two;
    long double tmp;
    char        *ret;

    nb_one = (uintmax_t)n;
    nb_two = ft_countdec((n - nb_one), 0.10);
    ret = ft_strjoin(ft_itoabase(nb_one, "0123456789", 10), ".");
    ret = ft_strjoin(ret, ft_itoabase(nb_two, "0123456789", 10));
    return (ret);
}

int     main()
{
    long double f = 6451532.54632;
    printf("%s\n", ft_dtoa(f));
    return 0;
}
```

Result of the test :

```
0.546320

boucle : nbr = 5.463200 ret = 5

boucle : nbr = 54.632000 ret = 54

boucle : nbr = 546.320000 ret = 546

boucle : nbr = 5463.199997 ret = 5463

boucle : nbr = 54631.999973 ret = 54631

boucle : nbr = 546319.999732 ret = 546319

boucle : nbr = 5463199.997321 ret = 5463199

boucle : nbr = 54631999.973208 ret = 54631999

boucle : nbr = 546319999.732077 ret = 546319999

boucle : nbr = 5463199997.320768 ret = 5463199997

boucle : nbr = 54631999973.207679 ret = 54631999973

boucle : nbr = 546319999732.076758 ret = 546319999732

boucle : nbr = 5463199997320.767274 ret = 5463199997320

boucle : nbr = 54631999973207.669704 ret = 54631999973207

boucle : nbr = 546319999732076.666718 ret = 546319999732076

boucle : nbr = 5463199997320766.363770 ret = 5463199997320766

boucle : nbr = 54631999973207660.605469 ret = 54631999973207660

boucle : nbr = 546319999732076575.718750 ret = 546319999732076575

boucle : nbr = 5463199997320765454.000000 ret = 5463199997320765454
5463199997320765454
6451532.5463199997320765454
```

Comment: I think you may have said the opposite of what you mean in your question. I believe what you are asking is why your double number loses precision after being multiplied by 10 a few times. Your question implies that you want it to lose precision but it's not.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes you are right i don't understand why it loose precision

Comment: Just to be sure, you are aware of how floating point values cannot represent all values?

Comment: You will find your answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems. In summary, all doubles and floats in any programming language are only approximations. You cannot count on the precision. Some languages have utilities or libraries that help you deal with this. I'm not sure if C has such a helper available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing precision when multiplying Doubles in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281341/losing-precision-when-multiplying-doubles-in-c)

Comment: BTW: `"%ld"` is not the specified to match `uintmax_t`.  Use `printf("%ju\n", ret);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various things that contribute to inaccuracies:

Use of a `double` `0.10` to represent one-tenth.  Given binary floating-point, this is a close approximation to one-tenth, but differs ever so slightly.

Code uses a `double`, not `long double` constant *near* the mathematical 6451532.54632.  That value, as a FP variable, is `6451532.546319999...` - the *closest* FP value to 6451532.54632.

Each iteration of `nbr /= baselen;` incurs a rounding error.  The cumulative effect of these rounding errors results in a lower precision output.

```
while ((nbr - ret) != 0) {
    nbr /= baselen;
```

---

> after 4 decimals, the precision is not wrong anymore.

Code is doing a fairly good job. It is not "wrong" after 4 decimals as the initial number is really something else.  **This is OP's primary problem.**  - incompatible view of what the output should be in C.

```
0.546320
boucle : nbr = 5.463200 ret = 5
boucle : nbr = 54.632000 ret = 54
boucle : nbr = 546.320000 ret = 546
boucle : nbr = 5463.199997 ret = 5463
boucle : nbr = 54631.999973 ret = 54631
boucle : nbr = 546319.999732 ret = 546319
boucle : nbr = 5463199.997321 ret = 5463199
boucle : nbr = 54631999.973208 ret = 54631999
boucle : nbr = 546319999.732077 ret = 546319999
boucle : nbr = 5463199997.320771 ret = 5463199997
boucle : nbr = 54631999973.207712 ret = 54631999973
boucle : nbr = 546319999732.077122 ret = 546319999732
boucle : nbr = 5463199997320.771217 ret = 5463199997320
boucle : nbr = 54631999973207.712173 ret = 54631999973207
boucle : nbr = 546319999732077.121735 ret = 546319999732077
boucle : nbr = 5463199997320771.217285 ret = 5463199997320771
boucle : nbr = 54631999973207712.171875 ret = 54631999973207712
boucle : nbr = 546319999732077121.718750 ret = 546319999732077121
boucle : nbr = 5463199997320771217.000000 ret = 5463199997320771217
5463199997320771217
```

To run a little better, `*10` rather than `/0.1`

```
//nbr /= baselen;
nbr *= 10;
```

Code should use a `long double` constant rather than `double` .

```
// long double f = 6451532.54632;
//                           v-- Add L
long double f = 6451532.54632L;
```

Output

```
0.546320
boucle : nbr = 5.463200 ret = 5
boucle : nbr = 54.632000 ret = 54
boucle : nbr = 546.320000 ret = 546
boucle : nbr = 5463.200000 ret = 5463
boucle : nbr = 54632.000000 ret = 54631
boucle : nbr = 546320.000000 ret = 546319
boucle : nbr = 5463199.999999 ret = 5463199
boucle : nbr = 54631999.999992 ret = 54631999
boucle : nbr = 546319999.999923 ret = 546319999
boucle : nbr = 5463199999.999233 ret = 5463199999
boucle : nbr = 54631999999.992331 ret = 54631999999
boucle : nbr = 546319999999.923311 ret = 546319999999
boucle : nbr = 5463199999999.233114 ret = 5463199999999
boucle : nbr = 54631999999992.331142 ret = 54631999999992
boucle : nbr = 546319999999923.311432 ret = 546319999999923
boucle : nbr = 5463199999999233.114258 ret = 5463199999999233
boucle : nbr = 54631999999992331.140625 ret = 54631999999992331
boucle : nbr = 546319999999923311.406250 ret = 546319999999923311
boucle : nbr = 5463199999999233114.000000 ret = 5463199999999233114
5463199999999233114
```

---

Note:  `long double modfl(long double value, long double *iptr);` instead of `(uintmax_t)n` and `(n - nb_one)` is a better way to break the `long double` into whole and fractional parts.